# Алгоритм изменения окружности

Tags: java, алгоритм

Прошу помощи с задачей ниже.

Есть две окружности **A** и **B**. Окружность **А имеет радиус n**, а **B имеет n / 2**. При этом окружность B находится внутри окружности A. Нужно у окружности A изменять радиус и центр, пока радиус окружности A не станет равен радиусу окружности B и центр окружности A не сместится в центр окружности B. Наглядно изображу это на рисунке ниже.

Может кто помочь с этим ? (в идеале кодом на java)

Наглядно: https://pp.userapi.com/c846124/v846124012/61118/jH7mN4j1F88.jpg

Comment: В чём проблема? Берём прямую, проходящую через центры. Берём центры и точки пересечения с окружностями с одной стороны. И начинаем уменьшать расстояния между точками в этих парах со скоростью в соответствии с соотношением расстояний в этих парах (чтобы они одновременно стали нулевыми).

Comment: @Akina Да, именно так я сразу и подумал, но не смог это написать кодом

Comment: Окружность на плоскости однозначно определяется центром и одной точкой. Так что можешь спокойно работать на прямой с вышеописанными 4 точками, одномерная-то задача куда как прощее будет.